# Add q/kdb Build System to Sublime 3

Tags: build, sublimetext3, kdb, q-lang

I am using Sublime Text 3 (on Mac OS) and would like to add a q/kdb build to it so I can run the q code directly from ST. I have the below build file:

```
{
"cmd": ["/Users/XXX/q/m32/q", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.q"
}
```

When in the CL this /Users/XXX/q/m32/q file.q runs just fine, but when within ST it doesn't do anything.
Any suggestions on what I m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial an error: all I had to do is remove the [**-u**] option from the command like below:

```
{
"cmd": ["/Users/XXX/q/m32/q", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.q"
}
```